# Как слить все ветки в master?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Инициализировал репозиторий. Создал ветку `branch-1`. Создал первый файл в ней, сделал commit. Создал ветку `branch-2`. Создал второй файл в ней, сделал коммит. Создал ветку `structure`. Переместил 2 ранее созданных файла из корня проекта в подпапку. Сделал commit. Переключился на `master`. Как теперь слить все изменения в `master` со всех веток? Сейчас, понятно, можно их названия и вручную переписать, но что, если бы этих веток я насоздавал сто штук? Как быть?

Comment: А если там конфликты - разгребать как будешь? Кто важнее будет из пяти файлов с конфликтами?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не совсем еще весь этот Git Flow понимаю, если честно, но, думаю, что в данной конкретной ситуации конфликтов не будет, ведь `master` еще пустая.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский то есть вы хотите сказать, что сливать изменения надо сразу перед переключением на другую ветку?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и еще. Стоит ли пушить каждую ветку отдельно, или, если слить все в `master`, то и изменения остальных веток будут нормально видны удаленно?

Comment: А зачем вам сто веток? Долгоживущих веток, как правило, две-три. master, dev, возможно, test. А короткие ветки живут пока выполняется конкретная задача. Если у вас их больше, чем можете удержать в голове, то используйте баг-трекер, и создавайте ветки с именами задач из него. У меня за 5 лет работы никогда не бывало более пяти активных коротких веток.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов многие руководства гласят "создавайте отдельную ветку для решения каждой проблемы". Вот я так и делаю.

Comment: @smellyshovel, и удаляйте после слияния с основной веткой.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов так реально надо делать? Не знал. А как тогда быть с подходом, который вы описали? Тот, где master, dev и test. Они ведь не удаляются?

Comment: Ветки делятся на 2 класса: долгоживущие (master, dev) и временные. Временные вливаются в dev, после тестирования и устранения всех недочетов, dev вливается в master. Временные после слияния удаляются. Каждая временная ветка на одну задачу. В идеале перед слиянием пересмотреть историю коммитов, чтобы каждый был осмысленный и не ломал компиляцию. По возможности, временные ветки на центральный сервер не отправляются. Чуть подробнее описано тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/

Comment: @ГерманБорисов благодарю :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как теперь слить все изменения в master со всех веток?

Как уже сказано в вопросе, можно вручную переписать названия веток в качестве аргументов команды git merge:

```
  git merge vetka1 vetka2 vetka3 ...
```

> Сейчас, понятно, можно их названия и вручную переписать, но что, если
>   бы этих веток я насоздавал сто штук? Как быть?

А для этого варианта можно поступить таким образом:

```
git checkout master && git branch -a | grep -ve " master$" | xargs git merge --
```

Данная команда объединит все ветки в master.